# Get Access token (JWT) for AADB2C in Blazor Serverside app

Tags: authentication, blazor, access-token, blazor-server-side, aad-b2c

I have a Blazor serverside application. To authenticate against it I have Azure AD B2C. I need to grab the access token (JWT) to authenticate against an API.

I have tried many possible answers of which none is working. The most common one is to use `await httpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");` (or "id_token").

For me in blazor this always returns null. If I try this in a demo asp.net API, the `GetTokenAsync` returns the correct JWT for me.

In my Blazor `program.cs` I have

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureB2C"));
```

I have also tried to use `AddOpenIdConnect` with `savetoken=true`

Questions are:

1. How do I get the token in a blazor serverside app?
2. What in my startup am I missing?

P.S. Also tried:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
{
    opt.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie().AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.Authority = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Authority").Value;;
    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration.GetSection("ClientId").Value;
    options.SaveTokens = true;
});
```

**[EDIT]** I have also tried the solution as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-6.0 and this also return null to me, even after I added `savetoken = true`

Comment: HttpContext is a bit of tricky in Blazor. Try accessing it within the .cshtml file which holds your blazor app.

Comment: @MarvinKlein thanks, I tried that as well. That also returned null for me. I also went and setup more in DI with AddJwtBearer with save token and this also did not help.